# Implement trait for Iterator+Clone: conflicting implementations

Tags: rust

I want to implement a trait `Foo` for `Iterator` (i.e., for all types that implement `Iterator`), so I wrote this:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl<F, FI> Foo for FI
    where F: Foo,
          FI: Iterator<Item=F> + Clone,
{
    fn foo(&self) {
        // Just for demonstration
        for x in self.clone() {
            x.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

So far, it compiles. However, when I additionally implement `Foo` for another type, like

```
impl Foo for u32 {
    fn foo(self) { println!("{} u32", self); }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
t.rs:5:1: 7:2 error: conflicting implementations for trait `Foo` [E0119]
t.rs:5 impl Foo for u32 {
t.rs:6     fn foo(self) { println!("{} u32", self); }
t.rs:7 }
t.rs:9:1: 18:2 note: note conflicting implementation here
t.rs:9 impl<F, FI> Foo for FI
t.rs:10     where F: Foo,
t.rs:11           FI: Iterator<Item=F> + Clone,
t.rs:12 {
t.rs:13     fn foo(&self) {
t.rs:14         for x in self.clone() {
```

How do I resolve this?

[(Playground)](http://is.gd/CDEH9q)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, that you can't. Since you can't make sure that `u32` won't at some point implement `Iterator`, the implementations do indeed conflict. If you really want to implement it for both `Iterator` and `u32`, you'll have to somehow make the implementations separate. One way to do this would be to implement it for `&'a FI` instead, since `u32` can never become a reference. Alternatively you could wrap the iterator in a struct, though this would make it slightly less ergonomic to use.

Comment: I see, thank you. What would Rust need to offer in order to make this work? Negated trait bounds? Specialized trait implementations?

Comment: Some kind of specialization is needed. We don't know exactly which solution works best yet.

Comment: But how do you know that `&'a u32` wont, at some point, implement `Iterator`? I don't think this really explains why impling for references works?